# What is the location of Bharata Varsha (khanda)?

Tags: scripture, vedas, puranas, india, geography

I have read somewhere(can't remember the source) the Bharatha Khanda governed by king Bharatha is submerged in the Hindu Mahasagara. Can anyone tell me where is Bharatha Khanda in current yuga? if it is submerged in ocean how come our current Hindustan got name Bhaaratha?? Is India just a part of original Bharatha Khanda?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Bharata Varsha**

> उत्तरं यत्समुद्रस्य हिमाद्रेश्चैव दक्षिणम् ।
>
> वर्षं तद् भारतं नाम भारती यत्र संततिः ।।
>
> -Vishnu Purana

The country/khand/region (varṣam) that lies north of the ocean and south of the snowy mountains (Himalaya) is called Bhāratam; there dwell the descendants of Bharata.

More Description of Bhárata-varsha can be found in [Vishnu Purana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp060.htm).

**Note**: This should be noted that there have been many kings named Bharata such as:

- king [Bharata in Priyavrata's lineage](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp058.htm) (Swáyambhuva or first Manwantara)
- king Bharata, younger brother of Lord Shri Rama (Vaivasvata or seventh Manvantara)
- king Bharata whose descendants were Kauravas/Pandavas (Vaivasvata or seventh Manvantara)

**हिन्दुस्थान**

> हिमालयात् समारभ्य यावत् इन्दु सरोवरम्।
>
> तं देवनिर्मितं देशं हिन्दुस्थानं प्रचक्षते॥
>
> -बृहस्पति आगम

हिमालय से प्रारम्भ होकर इन्दु सरोवर (हिन्द महासागर) तक यह देव निर्मित देश हिन्दुस्थान कहलाता है|

Is India just a part of original Bharata Varsha?

Yes, few countries (such as India, Pakistan, Bangladesh etc.) have emerged from Bharata Varsha.

Comment: Brihaspati Agam seems suspicious. Because "Hindusthanam" has never been in any Scriptures. And since it is an "Agam", it may have come later on. Who knows. ;)

Comment: @AnuragSingh This is a Geographical name here and not a name based on some religion...and this geographical location is aligned with Vishnu Purana..so i don't see any contradiction here..